# Update state with value from button element onClick

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks, state

I have some code below where I have decalared state in my parent component for size as an empty string.

What I am trying to do is create a handler function that will take the innerText of a button onClick and update the state of size with that value.

```
import { Child } from './Child';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Parent() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        name: 'bob',
        size: '',
    });

    const handleSize = (e) => {
        setState((state) => ({
            ...state,
            size: e.target.innerText,
        }));
    };


    return (
        <Child
            size={state.size}
            onClick={handleSize}
        />
    );
}
```

Here is the child component with the button that has innerText of 500. - I simply want to set the state of size to whatever value is inside my button element but this does not seem to work.

EDIT1: updated code to send size down to the child.

EDIT2: this current code throws a TYPE ERROR: 'Cannot read property 'innerText' of null' Is this because getting innerText of JSX elements is different than HTML elements?

EDIT3: I have answered my own question below. My handler function required adjustments.

```
    export const Child = ({
        size,
        onClick,
    }) => {
        return (
                <div>
                 <button onClick={onClick}>500</button>
                </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: That looks reasonable, but since the `size` isn't used anywhere, you wouldn't see an effect from the state change

Comment: Ah, see my updated code. I am now passing size down, however, where should I declare it to grab a static value from the button element? value={size} in button maybe?

Comment: You don't need to pass it down necessarily, you just need it to be used *somewhere* so you can visually see the state changing. Even a `console.log(size)` should do it - what are you trying to do with that property?

Comment: I will have a few buttons with different size values. Once clicked the updated state will update the size of another element (width).

Comment: Then you need to implement that width somewhere in order to see the effect of the state change, otherwise it's effectively invisible

Comment: in my project that is how it is setup. It is updating the width of a container, however, it is not working. It only works when I have already set a value for size in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the issue, my handler function needed some adjustments.

```
const handleSize = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setState((state) => ({
        ...state,
        size: value,
    }));
};
```

Instead of using the innerText of the button I decided to use value instead.

```
const { value } = e.target; //assigns the target value to my size property
```

Below is the updated button that has a static value of "500". The handleSize function will update the size onClick using the assigned value of the button.

```
export const Child = ({
    size,
    onClick,
}) => {
    return (
            <div>
             <button value="500" onClick={onClick}>500</button>
            </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const handleSize = (e) => {
  setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    size: e.target.innerText,
  }))
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates